# Verizon 3G on Samsung XE500C21 with 12.04

Tags: samsung, 3g

I recently upgraded to 12.04 on my Chromebook. However, I cannot seem to get my 3G connection working. Is this a known bug? Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is things to do after successfully put ubuntu in your samsung chromebook.

Go to software center and install `synaptic`.

For gobi Novatel Wireless you have to install **gobi loader** in synaptic or software center and reboot to activate your 3G mobile broadband.

With modem manager you can send sms check ussd and network. The link: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/modem-manager-gui.html

You can either see here the way to activate your GPS it's natively for gobi 2000 but it must be the same for gobi 3000: [thinkwiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Qualcomm_Gobi_2000) go to GPS section you must see something like   `echo "\$GPS_START" > /dev/ttyUSB2`, see more details there.

just try and keep searching ...